# How can we upload the file using http post?

Tags: post, httpclient

I am using HTTP API called HttpClient to upload the file using "post", but haven't been able to find any sample code for the same.

Any ideas? Any examples/implementations?

Edit:-

I meant HTTP API called HttpClient - See "Consuming RESTful Services with HttpClient" [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee391967.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You meant `WebClient`? Try this sample: [Download And Upload A File Using C#](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=115)

**EDIT**: Try this post: [Upload file with REST](http://forums.asp.net/p/1376821/2897707.aspx)